# Continue powershell script execution after system restart from last execution point

Tags: windows, powershell

**What i'm trying to do ?**

Create four files in local disk in the following order.
*Note : In my local machine and not in any server remotely.*

- Three files to be created
- Restart the system
- On system startup create another file

**Script i have used.**

```
get-job | remove-job -Force

function create-file {
   Param ([string] $a)
   $p = "D:\" + $a
   Write-Host $p
   if (!(Test-Path $p))
   {
      New-Item -path D:\$a -type "file" -value "my new text"
      Write-Host "Created new file and text content added"
   }
   else
   {
     Add-Content -path D:\$a -value "new text content"
     Write-Host "File already exists and new text content added"
   }
}
Workflow New-ServerSetup
{
   create-file "one.txt"
   create-file "two.txt"
   create-file "three.txt"
   Restart-Computer -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Wait
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 7
   create-file "four.txt"
   Unregister-ScheduledJob -Name NewServerSetupResume
}
$adm = "####"
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "####" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($adm, $pwd)
$AtStartup = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup
Register-ScheduledJob -Name NewServerSetupResume -Credential $cred -Trigger $AtStartup -ScriptBlock {Import-Module PSWorkflow; Get-Job -Name NewSrvSetup -State Suspended | Resume-Job}

New-ServerSetup -JobName NewSrvSetup
```

**Issues i'm facing**

- The execution returns **Cannot wait for local computer to restart**

i'm new to powershell things if any mistakes burden me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule a job first, then reboot without waiting.